# How to enable easily SSL in pod-to-service calls in Kubernetes

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, coredns

I need to be able to make requests from pod to service with SSL. What is the easiest way to do it?

In my setting I have configured CoreDNS to rewrite destination of each request from domain.com to service.namespace.svc.cluster.local. This is done because of the limitations of the caller software I am running in Kubernetes and I want these request be routed within Kubernetes.

Comment: The SSL connection is not a DNS related thing, you need to map your service to use a port that already has SSL and have the ability on your software to configure the connection as a SSL. Can you share some details of how you are connecting? can you share your yaml?

Comment: Yes, you're right that it is not a DNS related thing. I just wanted to share how the requests are routed within Kubernetes if that makes any difference.

I just want to be able to make requests from application instance A to instance B that both run in the same cluster. Those calls are like `https://example.com`.

I think I need to use self signed certs to do this but have no idea if it is the easiest way to do it:

[Managing TLS in a cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/)

Answer (score 1):

As per comments my advice is to use an `initContainer` to generate a new self-signed certificate on the pod that contains the service, configure your service to use this new certificate and make sure the client app doesn't validate the authority of the certificate.

This is a yaml example you can addapt to your service:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: alpine
  name: alpine
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: alpine
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: alpine
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: ssl-init
        image: wolmi/tools:v1.0.0
        command: ["sh", "-c", "openssl req -nodes -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout /tmp/ssl/key.pem -out /tmp/ssl/cert.pem -days 365 -subj "/C=DE/ST=NRW/L=Berlin/O=My Inc/OU=DevOps/CN=www.example.com/emailAddress=dev@www.example.com""]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: ssl-folder
          mountPath: /tmp/ssl
      containers:
      - image: alpine
        name: alpine
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - name: ssl-folder
          mountPath: /tmp/ssl
      volumes:
      - name: ssl-folder
        emptyDir: {}
```

On that `Deployment` you create a volume with the `emptyDir` parameter to allow containers to mount it and be able to write inside, then the `initContainer` generates the key and certificate files inside that folder and is available to all containers on the pod.

Comment: Actually I got it working with the [Kubernetes TLS management](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/). My problem was the IP address in the CSR example which is actually not needed.